# SOQL query like statement question

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql, search

I've made a search box in my lightning component to search for specific people in the database. However it seems like my like clause is not working correctly as it returns no guests.

I have debugged the attribute I am passing in and it is not null.

**Query**:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Guest__c> getSpecificGuests(id eventId, string guestName) 
{
    List<Guest__c> Guests =  [SELECT Id, Guest_Name__c, Seat__c,
                              FROM Guest__c 
                              WHERE Booking__r.Event__c=:eventId 
                              AND Seat__c=:null 
                              AND Guest_Name__c LIKE : guestName];
    return Guests;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the LIKE operator works with wildcards.

> Expression is true if the value in the specified fieldName matches the
>   characters of the text string in the specified value. The LIKE
>   operator in SOQL and SOSL is similar to the LIKE operator in SQL; it
>   provides a mechanism for matching partial text strings and includes
>   support for wildcards.
>
> - The % and _ wildcards are supported for the LIKE operator.
> - The % wildcard matches zero or more characters.
> - The _ wildcard matches exactly one character.
> - The text string in the specified value must be enclosed in single quotes.
>     The LIKE operator is supported for string fields only.
>     The LIKE operator performs a case-insensitive match, unlike the case-sensitive matching in SQL.
>     The LIKE operator in SOQL and SOSL supports escaping of special characters % or _.
>     Don’t use the backslash character in a search except to escape a special character.
>
> For example, the following query matches Appleton, Apple, and Appl,
>   but not Bappl: `SELECT AccountId, FirstName, lastname FROM Contact WHERE lastname LIKE 'appl%'`

So in your code, it would be:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Guest__c> getSpecificGuests(id eventId, string guestName) 
{
    guestName = '%' + guestName + '%';
    List<Guest__c> Guests =  [SELECT Id, Guest_Name__c, Seat__c,
                              FROM Guest__c 
                              WHERE Booking__r.Event__c=:eventId 
                              AND Seat__c=:null 
                              AND Guest_Name__c LIKE : guestName];
    return Guests;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome ! Glad I could help.